# Will Subclipse 1.4.4 work with Subversion 1.3.2

Tags: svn, subclipse

Will Subclipse 1.4.4 work safely with Subversion 1.3.2?

I am confused because its [changelog](http://subclipse.tigris.org/subclipse_1.4.x/changes.html) says

> NOTE: As of Subclipse 1.3.0, the minimum Subversion JavaHL requirement is 1.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclipse requires Subversion 1.5.x on the client.  A Subversion 1.5.x client can talk to any 1.x server, all the way back to 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean whether Subclipse 1.4.4 will work with a server that is 1.3.2?  If so, probably yes since clients tend to be updated more often than the servers, and thus they try to be backwards compatible. 1.3.2 is starting to get old though, if the client is based on subversion 1.5.

Comment: Yes I mean just that. I understand that SVN clients are backward compatible, but as you already said that 1.3.2 is old now. So this particular statement from changelog got me confused, if they have dropped support for Subversion 1.3.2, and now may essentially require Subversion 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

compatible with the server yes. But if you use it on a local working copy, your working copy gets updated to the new 1.5 format, so if you also use a command line svn client, or tortoise, you have to upgrade those as well.